# Cisco Basic Router Configuration

Tags: cisco, configuration, router

I'm pretty new to networking and I've just got started into using cisco packet tracer (a network simulator program).

My topology is basically a router, two switches connected to this router and per switch there are two computers.

one switch is connected on `fastethernet0/0` (`192.168.0.1`) the other is connected on `fastethernet0/1` (`192.168.1.1`)

Now if I use one of the computers on one switch to ping to one on the other switch it fails... however, computers on the same switch can ping each other and the router...

Like I said... I'm pretty new and I might be missing something here.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance! Dempsey

Comment: Is there a route between the two networks? You might want to add some static routes on the router and on the computers. On computers, set the right gateway, on the router check the routes to see wich network is bound on each physical interface.

Comment: Oh my... It was related to NOT setting the default gateway. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure that you have put a default gateway into each of the computers. No routes will be needed in your lab yet because the router will see each of the networks as connected.